# メッセージの表示時間を長くして欲しい

Tags: 機能の要求, 完了

先ほど、回答に投票したところ、青いポップアップに「あなたは最近質問に投票してない云々」と表示されましたが、表示時間が短く読めませんでした。
以前、回答にマイナス投票したことがあり、その時も何か表示されましたが読めませんでした。

これらのメッセージの表示時間は全体的にもっと長くて良いのではないでしょうか。

- とりあえず現在の10倍くらいの表示時間で
- ポップアップ右上に X を表示しておいて、それをクリックされたらすぐ閉じる

とかいかがでしょうか。

Comment: ブラウザとOSを教えてくれますか？（通常は「☓」ボタンを押すまで残りますが、ブラウザ環境かな？）

Comment: 修正してくださったようですが、念のため、OS は Arch Linux 64bit 版で ブラウザは Firefox 39.0 64bit 版です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。やっぱり文字数が関わっているjsだったため、コチラ側の問題でした。よく探しましたね！感謝です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

メッセージの表示時間は文字数で決まっていたため、日本語では非常に短かったです：

```
Math.max(2500, message.length * 40)
```

英語より日本語でメッセージが約半分の文字数になるため、2倍にしました：

```
Math.max(5000, message.length * 80)
```

適用は次回のビルドになります。